# functions added by innerHTML Template are triggered automatically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, string-interpolation

I came across this weird behavior. I want to add a html template containing an onclick behavior. So I tried the code below. The problem is that the function `callFunction` inside is executed automatically. My guess is that `callFunction` is executed when parsing the interpolation string in innerHTML. Is there a way around this behavior ? Thanks you

```js
const container = document.getElementById("test1");

function callFunction() {
  console.log('called');
}

container.innerHTML = `<button onClick="${callFunction()}"> Click on me</button>`
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions inside template literals are executed immediately. If you are creating an HTML string, you don't need to call the function in the same scope as it is created. You don't even need template literals. You just need to create a string with an `onClick` attribute.

```
container.innerHTML = '<button onClick="callFunction()"> Click on me</button>'
```

```js
const container = document.getElementById("test1");

function callFunction() {
  console.log('called');
}

container.innerHTML = `<button onClick="callFunction()"> Click on me</button>`
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
```